# Image selector more than one

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, upload

I have a page and the page has two picture selectors. I coded one of them for showing a picture when I select a picture file. But I want use them as separately. I tried it as attached code. Could you please help me how can I do as separately them? Also how can I create separately clear buttons with PHP, Javascript or jQuery?

I tried as my code and it's working just for one selector, not for other.

```
<form id="form1">
    <input type="file" id="image-1-selector">
    <img src="#" id="first-image">
    <button type="reset" onclick="clearFile(event)">Clear</button><br /><br />

    <input type="file" id="image-2-selector">
    <img src="#" id="second-image">
    <button type="reset" onclick="clearFile(event)">Clear </button>
</form>
```

```js
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $('#first-image').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#image-1-selector").change(function() {
    readURL(this);
});

var clearFile = function(event) {
    var output = document.getElementById('first-image');
    output.src = '';
};
```

Comment: This is my example code and it doesn't work like my asked

[MY EXAMPLE CODE](https://jsfiddle.net/underspeed/hsurwuod/#&togetherjs=dfuSRevdHA)

Comment: `var clearFile = function(event) {` will not work on jsfiddle.

Comment: yes, but you know what it is,  right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you can DRY up your code by using classes instead of ids to select the elements. From there you can use DOM traversal methods (in this case `next()` and `prev()`) to find the required elements to modify. Try this:

```
<form id="form1">
    <input type="file" class="image-selector">
    <img src="#" class="preview">
    <button type="reset" class="clear">Clear </button><br /><br />

    <input type="file" class="image-selector">
    <img src="#" class="preview">
    <button type="reset" class="clear">Clear </button>
</form>
```

```js
$(".image-selector").change(function() {
    var el = this;
    if (el.files && el.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $(el).next('.preview').prop('src', e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(el.files[0]);
    }
});

$('.clear').click(function(event) {
    $(this).prev('.preview').prop('src', '');
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/t5ersb7f/)